# Core Data Lightweight Migration Attribute Renaming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

I know there is a lot of questions about Core Data Migration here in Stack Overflow but I couldn't find a solution for my problem.

I successfully did a Lightweight migration by renaming an attribute called "LastName" in the source model to "Lastname" in the destination model. I did step by step to achieve this and it works except the fact that all of the previous data on the column "Lastname" now is lost. The new renamed attribute exists, i can insert new Entities and the values of the new inserted entities are ok. The problem holds on the old data and the old attribute. As apple documentation says, I put the **renaming identifier** of the new renamed attribute on the destination model to the name of the old attribute in the source model by XCode interface or by code and none works. My data on the renamed attribute is always lost.

Is that expected or a miss something?

Thnxs,

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this same issue where even with a renaming identifier, the data was being lost between the versions of my model. The model was jumping from Version 10 to 15 (with the change happening between versions 11 and 12), so the renaming identifier wasn't being pulled out, even when I included it in later versions. I also had the issue of how to deal with any later changes to the attribute.

In the end, I added the following code to the middle of the persistentStoreCoordinator method in the App Delegate (which is part of Apple's placeholder code when you setup a new project with Core Data added) before you connect the persistent store to the persistent store coordinator to perform lightweight migration:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [[[self managedObjectModel] entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"EntityName"];
NSPropertyDescription *property = [[entity attributesByName] objectForKey:@"NewAttributeName"];
[property setRenamingIdentifier:@"OldAttributeName"];
```

I then used this question on StackOverflow ([CoreData how to detect new version of an app so I can update the model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602274/coredata-how-to-detect-new-version-of-an-app-so-i-can-update-the-model)), which describes how to store the CFBundleVersion alongside the persistent store. That way, if you update the attribute's name again, you can check the current version of the persistent store and you know the latest version of the store, so you can choose the correct renaming identifier on the fly.